# isGooglePlayServicesAvailable always returns false

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to get the location using Google Play Services, but everytime I use the following code:

```
resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

I will get false back only as a result. Of course when I want to initialize a new location client (I know it s absolete) by

```
mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
```

I get false back only as well. 
Where is my mistake? Does Google Play Services need to be updated on the phone? I already checked for system updates, there is the newest one on it. It is a Galaxy S5 mini if that might help.

Answer (score 1):

The method isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returns 0 when succeeds, as you can see here:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#SERVICE_SUCCESS

So, 0 = false...

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities that you are getting that error

- Services are outdated
- Services are disabled/removed
- Another Samsung related bug

I have used this function to check if the services are new enough, otherwise I they will get a dialog and redirected to google play to update them

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        }
        else {
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It will display the error.